# 1987 GMC Sierra - Can't connect to OBD diagnostic connector

Tags: gmc, diagnostics, obd-i, sierra

I own a 1987 GMC Sierra and it has an ECU, I took it to a workshop to see if I've any issues, when they tried to connect a diagnostic reader to the connector (underneath the steering wheel) they couldn't. So they told me to replace the connector as its bad.

***Does anyone knows the part number for this connector?***

**Edit 1**

Followed comment link and was able to pull an error code

Error Code 44

Comment: That seems odd. Unless the ALDL is physically broken it's just a connector with pins in it. It's also easy to repin and just as much labor as replacing the connector. Maybe there are underlying issues with the serial data bus or power/ground circuit. You may want to have it checked somewhere else first.

Comment: [Can you try this process to see what codes you pull up?](https://youtu.be/UIKdbTFvyUU) Or if you can pull up any codes?

Comment: They tried to connect the code reader it won't show anything

Comment: Paulster, I saw the video and I did it, it shows 44, thx Paulster.